# Python daemon mode not returning information

Tags: python, python-3.x, database

I am using dameon mode in my code but I do not a bit understand how to use python daemon I am using this

```
def get_data():
    database = DB.connect("mydb.db")
    cur = database.cursor()
    sql_select_query = "SELECT * FROM data;"
    cursor.execute(sql_select_query, )
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    database.close()

    return data


def run():
    with daemon.DaemonContext():
        print(get_data())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

When I run my file it works but return nothing without daemon it returns db table. Please can anyone tell what function daemon does? Why my code does not return anything?

Thank you in advance!